# TypeError: this.state.searchResults.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

The moment i try to enter in the search box its leading to the typeerror. I have declared the searchResults as a state. but its still throwing an error. Am i not calling the state properly? What should i change? is it the map method that i'm writing it ?

Sorry i'm new to react could someone possibly tell what i'm doing wrong thanks.

```
Search.js

    import React, { Component }  from 'react';
import './Search.css';
import axios from 'axios';

class Search extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            searchResults : []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount () {
        const token = 'Bearer Wookie2019';
        axios.get('https://wookie.codesubmit.io/movies?q=<search_term>',{
           headers: {
             'Authorization': token
           }
         }).then(response => {
           this.setState({movies : response.data.movies});
        console.log(response);
      });
    }

    searchHandler = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            searchResults : event.target.value
        })
        console.log(this.searchResults);
    }
    render(){
        return (
            // <div className="search" >
            //         <input className = "form-control" type="text" avlue="inputVal" onChange = {this.searchHandler}/>                
            //         {/* <i className="fas fa-search"></i> */}
            //         <button className ="btn btn-info">Search</button>
            //         <div className ="searchres">
            //         </div>
            // </div>
            <div>
                <form>
                    <input className = "form-control" placeholder = "Search Movies" ref = { input => this.search = input} onChange = {this.searchHandler}/>
                </form>
                <div className = "searchresults">
                    { this.state.searchResults.map(searchResult => <searchResult movie={this.state.searchResults}>{searchResult.title}</searchResult>)}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Search;

    
    Title.js
    
    import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
    import Search from '../Search/Search';
    import './Title.css';
    
    
    const Title = (props) => {
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <div className ="conatiner">
                    <div className ="row titlehead">
                        <div className="col-6">
                            <h3 className = "title">WOOKIE <br/> MOVIES</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div className = "col-6 searchMovie">
                            <Search {...props} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </Fragment>
        )
    }
    
    export default Title
```

Comment: where is your `searchHandler` method?

Comment: also components should be uppercase `<SearchResult>`

Comment: @DrewReese i have updated that its throwing an typeerror. could you please have a look.

Comment: @souravsatyam i have updated that but its throwing a type error

Comment: Ack, you edited your code to provide the correct handler. What is the type error?

Comment: @DrewReese TypeError: this.state.searchResults.map is not a function

Comment: what you are doing with updating state in `searchHandler ` method. Seems like the logic that goes in `componentDidMount ` should have been in `searchHandler` method.

Comment: Secondly you are getting type error because `componentDidMount` you are updating state `searchResults` which must have been `undefined`. definetely not an array though.

Comment: @souravsatyam you mean should i call axios method inside the search handler? I have passed null to searchResults still i'm getting the same thing

Comment: please check response and update serachResults accordingly

Answer (score 1):

## Issues

If I had to guess I would say your `onChange` handler is setting your state to be undefined, or rather, to whatever you are inputting, which is a string, not an array.

Another issue is that you attempt to fetch your data when the component mounts, not when a search is entered.

The search is never invoked after mounting.

## Solution

I suggest using the form's `onSubmit` event to do the search. Provide the input with an `id` attribute that can be accessed from the `onSubmit` event object. Pass the entered value to a computed query string.

```
import React, { Component }  from 'react';
import './Search.css';
import axios from 'axios';

class Search extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      searchResults : []
    }
  }

  searchHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const searchTerm = event.target.searchTerm.value
    const token = 'Bearer Wookie2019';
    axios.get(`https://wookie.codesubmit.io/movies?q=${searchTerm}`,{
      headers: {
        'Authorization': token
      }
    }).then(response => {
      this.setState({ movies: response.data.movies });
      console.log(response);
    });
  };

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={searchHandler}>
          <input
            id="searchTerm"
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="Search Movies"
          />
          <button type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
        <div className="searchresults">
          {this.state.searchResults.map(searchResult => <searchResult movie={this.state.searchResults}>{searchResult.title}</searchResult>)}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```